# How to correctly declare function with templated class as return type in header?

Tags: c++, templates, header, declaration, definition

I have a template class declared in a header file.

```
// Matrix.h
template <class X> class Matrix {};
```

In another header file I have a function declaration which has an instantiation of that template class as return type:

```
// OtherModule.h
Matrix<double> do_stuff();
```

In the source file of the other module I include the header of the Matrix class:

```
// OtherModule.cpp
#include "Matrix.h"

Matrix<double> do_stuff() {
  // do stuff
}
```

How do I make the compiler know what `Matrix<double>` is in the OtherModule header file without including Matrix.h in the header itself?

I tried forward declaration as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file):

```
// OtherModule.h
template class Matrix<double>

Matrix<double> do_stuff();
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try this `template<class> class Matrix; Matrix<double> do_stuff;` But why not just include the header? Any user of `do_stuff` will need it anyway.

Comment: I am hesitant to include it in OtherModule.h because, as suggested in the solution in the above link, I included the entire implementation file (TMatrix.ipp) at the end of the header file TMatrix.h. So if I understand correctly, including TMatrix.h in OtherModule.h would also include the entire implementation of TMatrix. So then if I now include OtherModule.h in yet another sourcefile that needs do_stuff(), I will have also included the entire implementation of TMatrix. Is that correct and would that be a problem?

Comment: I guess the underlying issue that confuses me is wether I have to include the header file let's say A.h in another header B.h when A.h declares a class that B.h uses as function return or argument type. Because in some cases it seems to be sufficient to only include A.h in the source file B.cpp and not in the header but in other cases (like the above) apparently not.

Comment: Every translation unit that needs to *call* `do_stuff` also needs the definition of `Matrix`, including at least the copy/move constructor and the destructor definitions. If `Matrix` declares those, then the `.ipp` file is also needed.

Comment: [What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@n. m. could be an AI: Your first comment accomplishes what I was trying to do. Whether it actually makes sense to do it like that is a seperate question, I guess.

Anyway with the following code it works:

```
// OtherModule.h:

template <class> class Matrix;
Matrix<double> do_stuff();
```